# English native, How do you add the/a into some word?

Tags: articles

I easily omit using a/the article in conversation, because my brain have hard time what verb I should use, what noun I sould use while conversation. So I mostly forgot using articles.

So English native speaker, do you add it because you feel awkward withou it? Or do you remember Grammar book's teaching how you should a/the to it.

For example:
"The lord of the rings"
You feel awkward with only 'lord of ring'.

So your tongue is used to using these 6 words. So only 'lord' is meaningless word to your tongue.

1. My lord
2. Your lord
3. That lord
4. Lords
5. The lord
6. A lord

Thus 'lord of ring' makes you feel weird, so you sponteneously use 'The lord', 'The ring'.
Do you think keep my tongue saying those 6 words like millions times will make me spontaneously say 'The lord'?

Do you think this is right approach to make me speak like Native?

Comment: Native speakers of a language that uses articles certainly don't use them because of what the grammar book says; we learn how to use them as a natural part of learning to speak when we are children. _The Lord of the Rings_ is not a good example because it's the title of a book (and film series); some titles begin with an article and some don't. You can look up _when to use the definite and indefinite article_.

Comment: I don't know what your native language is, perhaps it's one of the Chinese dialects, but it's almost certain that there are parts of it that you use naturally that non-native speakers find hard. For instance Chinese has measure words for all nouns and these are very rare in English. Also Chinese has a lot of 'structural particles' which have no equivalent in English. Native Chinese speakers use these naturally but foreigners have to learn them. Articles in English are the same, there are English speakers who don't know what an indefinite article is but still use 'a' and 'an' correctly.

Comment: My only advice is to immerse yourself in the culture of the native English speakers you want to immitate.  Consume their television, podcasts, and movies, read books, and look for anything you can do to hear and practice more with native speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the title of Tolkien's classic book is "The Lord of The Rings", many fans refer to it as "Lord of the Rings", and commonly abbreviate it to "LOTR".

What this really shows is that the first definite article in this book title is somewhat redundant.

"Lord" can literally mean '*master*', and in many contexts can be the highest rank in something. For that reason, in a context where there can clearly only be one lord, the definite article is redundant because there is no other lord to distinguish them from. In the case of Tolkien's novel, 'the Lord of the Rings' is the one person who held or controlled all the rings, so if there can be only one, there isn't a strict need for the definite article, although it is certainly not incorrect! For comparison, you might want to consider the classic novel '*Lord of the Flies*'.

However, there are other contexts where there are many 'lords'. In British politics, 769 lords make up the House of Lords. In British history, persons were designated 'Lord of the Manor', a unique manorial title, but not a unique title throughout the entire country. Both could be referred to as "**a** lord", as they are not unique. As a title, we just call someone "Lord [surname]".

My answer to your question of how to speak more like a native would be to focus more on learning when to use the definite and indefinite articles in everyday speech, rather than the titles of books which are determined by the whim of the author.